# BigQuery Hash Index Feature

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Where can I find information regarding hash indexing in BigQuery? Is this feature secondary indexing?

Comment: What index are you referring to? did you have a look at this paper? https://cloud.google.com/files/BigQueryTechnicalWP.pdf
its says that _• Most importantly, note that there was no index or any pre-aggregated values
for this table prepared in advance. _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't have any concepts of indexes. It performs a full table scan with every query (partitioned tables excepted). It's used for pure OLAP - it's not relational nor should be used for OLTP.